# Question about relationship between two inequality equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

Known:
$$X_1=A_1+B_1$$
$$X_2=A_2+B_2$$
$$X_2=A_2+B_2$$
$$B_1\le B_2 $$

$$B_2\le K*B_1 $$
$$ K\ge1$$
$$ X_1\le X_2$$
Is it true that:
$$X_2\le K*X_1 $$
If not true, are there conditions that make it true?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:   not true in general, but sufficient conditions could be $\,A_2 \le K \cdot A_1\,$ or $\,A_2 \le A_1\,$, since:

$$
X_2 =A_2 + B_2 \le A_2+ K \cdot B_1 = A_2+K \cdot(X_1-A_1) = K \cdot X_1+ A_2 - K \cdot A_1
$$